# How many quests does each companion have?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I just completed a companion quest for Khem Val, and I'm wondering how many more (if any) he's likely to throw my way if I give him more gifts?

His affection is around the 3600 mark, I've had him with me for the vast majority of the game so far, and he alikes most of my decisions -- yet the quest was still three levels below me and disapointingly easy. So I'd like to get the others early if there are any and do them at the appropriate level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every classes first companion has three major quests that will take you off the ship; one per act.

This is in addition to the 'quests' that are your on-ship conversations with all of your crew members. These, like the three 'major' quests, are unlocked by a combination of affection and class story progression. If you get your companion affection substantially ahead of the plot curve (say, via gifts), you can use these conversations to see a nice XP boost at the start of each chapter.

Comment: What about the other companions?

Comment: I'm assuming they don't have these quests, just occasional conversations that grant xp/affection?

Comment: That's correct. Other companions won't send you off the ship on quests. The conversations often feel like half-finished hooks to do exactly that, but rather than resulting in a quest, you instead get a fade-to-black followed by a conversation with your companion about their recent trip to Nar Shadaa to settle an old score or whatever.